# Hi I am new to apex , please help me out with this error

Tags: apex

```
public class EmployeeInfo
{
    public integer employeecode;
    public string empName, address, emailId;
    public decimal salaryAmount;
    pubic boolean isActive;
    public date joiningDate, birthdate;
    
}
```

executing the code through anonymous window

```
EmployeeInfo emp = new EmployeeInfo();

system.debug('Employee code is...:'+ emp.employeecode);
system.debug('Employee name is...:'+ emp.empname);
system.debug('salary Amount is...:'+emp.salaryAmount);
system.debug('Address is ....:'+ emp.address);
system.debug('Email id is...:' + emp.emailid);
```

Error is Variable does not exist: employeecode

Answer (score 2):

You spelt `public` as `pubic`, so the class failed to compile/deploy. Since the latest version of the class wasn't saved, it didn't have `employeeCode` as a property you could access.

Comment: thank you for the reply ...it didn't have employeeCode as a property you could access. wat does it mean

Comment: @sai The code on the server does not match the code you're looking at, because it failed to save.